# Django - Search related fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(_("First name"), max_length=30, )
    last_name = models.CharField(_("Last name"), max_length=30, )
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email"), blank=True, max_length=75)

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    phone = models.CharField(_("Phone Number"), blank=True, max_length=30, )
    primary = models.BooleanField(_("Primary"), default=False)
```

My admin.py:

```
class ContactOptions(AutocompleteAdmin):
    list_display = ('last_name', 'first_name')
    ordering = ['last_name']
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    related_search_fields = { """??? I want to search the Phone Numbers ???""" }
```

How to search the Phone Numbers in Django admin? Please give some code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UPDATE: this answer is outmoded, see the [answer from elsadek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26943183/79225) instead

---

You're asking to be able to follow a reverse relation (ie, from PhoneNumber back to Contact) but I don't believe the double-underscore `__` trick for spanning tables will work here.

If your Contact had the key to the PhoneNumber model instead of the current set-up:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ...
    phone = models.ForeignKey(PhoneNumber)
```

then in the admin config you could do:

```
search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone__phone')
```

Comment: Please don't touch my models :(

Comment: In that case, you can't do it in the admin.

Answer (score 18):

Just in case someone comes over this question, in Django 1.6, search in reverse relation is indeed possible.

In your phone model add **related_name="phonesList"** to contact field

```
contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="phonesList")
```

Now in search_field you can use the double undescore to go from conatct to phones like this:
**phonesList__phone**

```
search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email','phonesList__phone')
```